# Can you set the results of a search results web part from JavaScript search executor?

Tags: search, jsom

If I am retrieving results from a JSOM keyword query like so...

//Create Search Executor Object

```
 var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(context);
```

//Execute the Query

```
  Var results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
```

If I have a Search Results WebPart on the page, am I able to set these results to the Search Results WebPart?

Comment: If you have a Search Results web part on the page, why not just add the query to the web part?

Comment: Because the result source is dynamic.

Comment: I only want to use the web part for its ui

Comment: There is a setting in the web part for "Query results provided by" but I don't know what the web part is looking for on the page.

Comment: I am looking to do it in JavaScript

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am encountering an issue with queries being too large for IE to handle as a GET request.

Comment: Not as is but you can always filter the result set and use pagination.  I accomplished this with knockout js